# Can anyone tell me what this sans serif font is?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

I really need to know what font is in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just plain and simple Arial and Arial bold. A handy tool to identify fonts is [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

[image: partial Arial reproduction of screenshot]

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds as I was typing! The `R`, `M` and `1` give it away. I don't think we've been asked to identify Arial before...

Comment: Subtle but recognizable diffrences with Helvetica, yes. :)

Comment: Is it really simple Arial?  I tend to think it is Arial Regulat? @Bakabaka

Comment: I used your pic as a template when creating mine in PhotoShop. My Arial text layer practically disappeared when superimposed on your pic. 'Regular' is just the indication of the typeface's default weight.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically of sans family og ghothic style as all the sides of the font are similar in width . 
if you want to know exact font name than you can upload font image to :
http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ 
and it will you lot of exact font and similar looking font .

thanks